# array, not applicable for argument

Tags: java, arrays, inherited-constructors

I want to add a Guest to the array guests,  can you guys see what am doing wrong, or cant I call a  a string, constructor, constructor ?

The error says: `the method addGuest(Guest) in the type  table is not applicable for the argument ( String, Tea,Cake)`. I am trying to put a guest in to an array

here is my code.

```
guests[0]=table.addGuest("Alice",new Tea("RoseShip Tea",false,true),new Cake("Chocolate Sponge"));
```

and constructor of class Guest is like this:

```
public Guest(String name, Tea newTea, Cake newCake)
```

constructor of class Tea is:

```
public Tea(String name, boolean suiker, boolean melk)
```

Class Cake:

```
public Cake(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

addGuest method:

```
public void addGuest(Guest guest)
```

and what am trying to do is this:

```
guests[0]=table.addGuest(new Guest("Alice"),new Tea("RoseShip Tea",false,true),new Cake("Chocolate Sponge"));
```

Comment: It would help to know which programming language this is.

Comment: programming language is java

Comment: What has this got to do with inherited constructors? The error message is pretty clear - your `addGuest` method takes a single parameter of type `Guest`, not a `String`, a `Tea` and a `Cake`.

Comment: you call addGuest on a "table" and then explicitly assign the return value of addGuest to guests[0] (the first element of guests). This is not "trying to put a guest in to an array", rethink your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use,

```
Guest g = new Guest("Alice",new Tea("RoseShip Tea",false,true),new Cake("Chocolate Sponge"));
table.addGuest(g);
```

instead of

```
guests[0]=table.addGuest("Alice",new Tea("RoseShip Tea",false,true),new Cake("Chocolate Sponge"));
```

because you pass the arguments required for the constructor of Guest to the wrong method(`addGuest(<Guest>)`), which requires the actual Guest-object.

**EDIT**
Further, this will also not work

```
guests[0]=table.addGuest(...);
```

because `table.addGuest(...)` is of type `void`, so it wont return anything, so you will get an compiler error.
I recommend rethink the use of `guests[]` , you could probably use a collection (like `LinkedList` or  `ArrayList`) to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing wrong parameters to the method. addGuest can only take guest parameter in your program. either you hava to overload method to support your parameters like addGuest(String, Tea,Cake) or you have to pass only guest name as parameter.

Comment: yes but the constructor of Class guest is like this 'public Guest(String name, Tea newTea, Cake newCake)'